# How to make .editorconfig naming violations visible to dotnet build? (IDE1006 warnings)

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, fxcop, editorconfig

I have recently implemented custom `FxCopAnalyzers` policies via `.editorconfig` for a `netcoreapp3.1` c# project. I now have lots more warnings and hints in Visual Studio for code style and naming policies when the file is open. When the file is closed, the `IDE1006` naming violations disappear but I can still get a solution-wide report by running `Analyze > Run Code Analysis > On Solution`.

However, I'm struggling to get the `IDE1006` naming violations to show up in a command line `dotnet build`. I've already incorporated `dotnet format --check` into the CI process which is great for the whitespace rules, but no help with naming violations such as an invalid prefix for a private field.

To summarise, how can I make my CI build pick up `IDE1006` warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not supported yet, the issue that tracks this can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/33558).